# Redo action for textbox?

Tags: vb.net

How can I make a redo function to redo an action in a textbox (with a button)?

Comment: Its already in Windows - just hit Ctrl-Z again

Comment: Make a `Sub` called `Redo` with a `Handles` clause at the end, and put your redo logic inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows natively tracks and handles one level of UnDo for a TextBox control, via [Ctrl-Z].  But it also implements a ReDo using the same key, toggling between what was in the control (UnDo) and what they just typed (ReDo).  Net implements both via the `Undo` method:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Undo()
End Sub
```

Once 2 different strings have been entered in the control it should toggle between them otherwise, it will act as a simple UnDo.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listview out of your form. On the TextChange event you will have to add the current text in the listview item. Just make the sequence correctly for redo undo like history.

Comment: This is quite wrong.  The OP is asking about REDo not UNDo.  A ReDo history item would only only be created when the user selects UnDo.    The TextChanged event would have nothing to do with either one.  When they Leave the control a new UnDo history item might be made (not part of the OP), but it would also CLEAR the ReDo stack since it is a new history.

Comment: Umm you are quite right.